# Dynamic url for link with php different php variables

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic-url

My title may not be the good one, i tried my best.

I want to load different links through ajax, and I want them to direct them to different pages, based on the links URL they have.

the `href` value is `php` variable that is changing.

In simple case we do this :
`<a href = "somepage.php?varible = 'ifany' ">`

But I've pages with different names and these names are changing through variable.

How can I have the page name with their extension and with the ability to send variables to that page dynamically, how can I do that ?

The following `links` are loaded with different `href` values through ajax.

```
if ($run = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `day` from `foodd_schedule` WHERE `week` = '$week' group by day"))
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {
?>

    <a href="<?php echo $row['day'] . '.php'; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['day'] ?>"><?php echo $row['day']; ?></a>

<?php
    }
}
```

In `href` value I'll have different **days** with that I've appended extension i.e `php`, I don't know is this right or wrong?

How can I append variables to the dynamically created page names?

I want to append an `id` to these dynamically created links.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the code for your `href` value

```
<?php echo $row['day'] . '.php?id=' . $id; ?>
```

I would recommend to create a function where you would build your url. For the GET parameters use `http_build_query` function see the [doc](http://docs.php.net/manual/da/function.http-build-query.php).

**Update:**

How to append multiple params using `http_build_query`, full example:

```
<php
if ($run = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT `day` from `foodd_schedule` WHERE `week` = '$week' group by day")) {
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run)) {

        $params = [
            'id' => $id,
            'foo' => 'some string',
        ];
        $query = http_build_query($params); // generate url encoded string
?>
        <a href="<?php echo $row['day'] . '.php' . (!empty($query) ? '?' . $query : ''); ?>" value="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>" name="<?php echo $row['day']; ?>"><?php echo $row['day']; ?></a>
<?php
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: and to append more than one , how could I do then ?

Comment: as I wrote see `http_build_query` function. You create an assoc array with all you params and the function creates the query string for you, which you will attach to the  file name using `?`

Comment: Yeah , that's solve the problem, but please let me know what if I don't use that function and I want to append variables via `&`

Comment: I'm asking for multiple variables because I don't know where to use that function ! @Nik

Comment: This is also ok, just not flexible enough, plus the function `Generates a URL-encoded query string` - means if you have string values in the params this you would need to do using `urlencode`

Comment: So how would I append more than one variables with and (&)? @Nik

Comment: Perfect, and to use these variables on another page, do I need something like `isset` stuff ?

Comment: Yes, to get them in `<day>.php` you need `$id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : null;` plus filtering/validation afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to append an id to these dynamically created links.

You already have the format for how you intend to append query string values:

```
<a href="somepage.php?varible=ifany">
```

Simply apply that format to the HTML you're outputting:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['day'].'.php';?>?id=someValue"
```

If `someValue` is also coming from a variable, then use the same method you're already using to output that variable:

```
<a href="<?php echo $row['day'].'.php?id='.$row['someValue'];?>"
```

I guess basically what I'm saying is that you're already outputting dynamic values.  So in order to output more dynamic values simply re-apply the knowledge you already have.